# How to scan Improper Dihedral in Orca?

Tags: density-functional-theory, ab-initio-calculations, orca

I am using Orca 4.2.1 for the ab initio calculation. Scanning the redundant coordinates I am trying to scan potential surface for different type of bonds, angles and dihedrals. How can I do so for improper dihedrals in Orca? I will use these surface scanning for forcefield potential fitting.

Comment: Doesn't the normal way of defining dihedrals work? I feel like it should work for both dihedral and improper dihedral coordinates.